# Scala Singleton objects

Tags: java, scala

I have the following question:

> Deﬁne an Origin object that extends java.awt.Point. Why is this not
>   actually a good idea? (Have a close look at the methods of the Point
>   class.)
>
> import java.awt.Point
>
> object Origin extends Point { }

But I really don't know why it's not a good idea to extend this class. Could someone enlighten me please?

Comment: Hint: What would happen if you would call one of the `set...()` methods? (Keep in mind that it's a singleton).

Comment: The values of the coordinates would be modified?

Comment: The problem is encapsulation leak, any code everywhere could read or write the state making it impossible to control and hard to debug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "contract" of Java `Point` is here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html. Point is designed to be mutable as noted by @Jesper and has mutators like `setLocation(<overloaded>)`. Given this information here are the disadvantages of using it like this and using it at all:

- It's a mutable object which is even in Java is a thing to avoid.
- When you are creating a singleton of the Point like this `object Origin extends Point { }` you can only have a single Origin object in the entire application (not going to talk about classloaders and their scope).
- If your intention is to have only a single Origin object you should still protect yourself from mutability that Point comes with. Otherwise you are letting anybody change the origin.

I hope you see the contradiction by now: on one hand if you want to have a single origin in application and be able to reason about it you would want your origin never change (immutable). On the other hand if you don't want to have a single origin, then creating a singleton does not help at all.

Comment: I suppose I was thinking that you could have a single instance of an origin but perhaps that origin could change over time.

It seems like everyone is just assuming that because the object is named 'Origin' it will only ever have one value which shouldn't be mutable. I'm not 100% sure I agree with this assumption- the question itself doesn't define that Origin only ever have a single value that doesn't change.

Comment: Yes I agree with you that there is no requirement of immutability of Origin in the question. However, names mean a lot to developers when they read code. We have to assume and expect certain behaviour when seeing a name of a variable or a method. Perhaps a better name would be `CurrentOrigin` to indicate that it can change. On the other hand mutability comes in flavours. You can have a `var` in Scala referencing an immutable object (preffered usually) vs `val` referencing a mutable object (this case). ...

Comment: ... Functional programming and immutability make it easy to reason about your code because you don't have to think about side effects and what state the Origin is in. You can have some other part of your code deal with change propagation of an Origin.

Comment: Consider how would you test your code or replace Point implementation with another object if you are using statically initialized object and referencing it directly - not possible. You are already using statically initialized object it invites for problems like these. This violates loose coupling principle.

Comment: I personally think Point is a horrific class for many reasons. I don't know if there are any practical reasons to make it such, but I can't think of any. Take a look at this method `public void setLocation(double x, double y)` - I think it should not compile instead of rounding to int. It has 3! setters and 3! constructors - quite a lot for something that is basically a `Tuple2[+T1, +T2]`. It makes it hard to reason about to start with. Then you make it accessible to the whole application and you'll have to spend mental cycles trying to keep track of who changes it and when...

Comment: ... Throw in concurrency and you get a hell lot of mess from a simple class like that.

Comment: I'm not even talking about concurrent access control / synchronization. That is impossible in this example.

Comment: Yeah, all really valid points - thanks for so much explanation. Just because you can do something doesn't mean you should, and especially not without considering the consequences.